# whats the best practice with serialized AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been working on an android application that depends completely on information from a database on a local server(info comes in form of json array from a webservice).

So I have been using multiple AsyncTasks, where I would execute the first one in OnCreate and the 2nd would be in the OnPostExecute of the first and so goes the chain.
my question is what is the best practice for this? I mean is it better to have one AsyncTask that executes all my http get/post requests? 
this is sample of my code:
code for first http AsyncTask:

```
public class httpAddProduct extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        String  rs;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dd_dialog=showProgressDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String proID=selectedCatProID.get(itemIndex);
                String link = "http://"+IP+"/H2O.asmx/Add_Product?OrderID="+orderId+"&ItemNo="+proID
                        +"&Qty="+Qyt;
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(link));
                client.execute(request);
                addPro=true;
                isChanged=true;
                rs = "sucessful";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                rs = "Fail";
            }
            return rs;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s.equals("sucessful")){
                new httpGetOrder().execute();
dd_dialog.hide();
        }}

    }
```

and here is second http code:

```
public class httpGetOrder extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        String result, rs;
        JSONArray jArray;
        Boolean isEmpty=true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String link = "http://"+IP+"/H2O.asmx/Get_Order?OrderID="+orderId;
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(link));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                String[] separated = result.split(">");
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(separated[2]);
                jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("OrderItems");
                lineIDs = new ArrayList<>();
                productNames = new ArrayList<>();
                QYTs = new ArrayList<>();
                unitPrice = new ArrayList<>();
                subtotal = new ArrayList<>();
                FatherCateg=new ArrayList<>();
                isPrinted1=new ArrayList<>();
                isPrinted2=new ArrayList<>();
                isPrinted3=new ArrayList<>();
                note=new ArrayList<>();
                isEmpty=true;
                int jlen=jArray.length();
                if(jlen>0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jlen; i++) {
                        if(jArray.getJSONObject(i)!=null) {
                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            lineIDs.add(json_data.getString("LineID"));
                            productNames.add(json_data.getString("En_Name"));
                            unitPrice.add(json_data.getString("UnitPrice"));
                            subtotal.add(json_data.getString("SubTotal"));
                            QYTs.add(json_data.getString("Qty"));
                            FatherCateg.add(json_data.getString("Father"));
                            note.add(json_data.getString("LineNote"));
                            isPrinted1.add(json_data.getString("IsPrinted"));
                            isPrinted2.add(json_data.getString("IsPrinted2"));
                            isPrinted3.add(json_data.getString("IsPrinted3"));
                        }

                    }
                    isEmpty=false;
                }
                rs = "sucessful";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                rs = e.getMessage();
            }
            return rs;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s.equals("sucessful")){
                try{

                    if(isEmpty){
                        grandt.setText("0");
                        invoiceList.setAdapter(null);
                        dd_dialog.hide();
                    }else{
                        makeInvoice();
                        listviewAdapter adapter = new listviewAdapter(SelectCategory.this, list);
                        invoiceList.setAdapter(adapter);

                        if(addPro)
                        {invoiceList.setSelection(adapter.getCount()-1); addPro=false;}
                        else
                            invoiceList.setSelection(selectionIndex);

                        new httpGetTotal().execute();
                    }}
                catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }}

        }

    }
```

yet this excites a third AsyncTask.
I know the code is too long :/ sorry
but my app is getting bigger and slower, I need advise with this problem.

Comment: I do not know what you are gaining by having several `AsyncTask` instances that you execute serially. Personally, I would recommend deleting everything you have there, and use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It offers better threading than `AsyncTask` and integrates better JSON parsing (using Gson) than what you are doing with `JSONObject`.

Comment: honestly first time I hear about Retrofit, I will read about it now, thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that the webservice is built using .NET
should that make any difference ?

Comment: No, what technology is used on the server generally should not affect the technology that is used on the client.